# Using drupal profile date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, drupal, date, profile

I am using drupal databas ein one of my application. Drupal profile saves date in following format:

a:3:{s:5:"month";s:1:"2";s:3:"day";s:2:"18";s:4:"year";s:4:"1995";}

I can read this with data reader but how to convert in a proper display like DD/MM/YYYY or YYYY/MM/DD

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can kind of see the values for month, day and year in that zany string. Presumably there is something in VB that can help you parse and glue together the string as you need it?

You might look into how PHP's [unserialize()](https://www.php.net/unserialize) works, that will reformat the string to a more usable array.

Answer (score 0):

Most of all, dont use profile, use content_profile and cck. Problem solved. Unserializing PHP serialization can get a bit hairy.